# User to User app request not showing a message

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook requests dialog not showing message to recepient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297853/facebook-requests-dialog-not-showing-message-to-recepient)

I tried to send a suer to user request in a facebook app using the following code

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
message: 'how are you dude'});
```

the request dialog appears and the notification is also sent to the intended user,but the user does not receive the message in the notification.It only shows..ABC sent you a request for this fillowing app..
I do not understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: So should i use the new message parameter to get that working

Comment: No, it was an undocumented feature which has also stopped working lately. So unfortunately there is no way I could find. Even I have the same issue.

Comment: But how do the more popular apps mange to show the message in the notification.For Example i got a request from Song Pop-Are you ready for the country challenge...How did they manage to do it??

Comment: Even this is a mystery to me.. My guess is either they have a minimum user engagement or they have special permission from Facebook. Who knows which apps does Facebook has special relations with which is not public? Just my two cents even though I don't really know the reason answer to this particular question.